# Typescript Interface with function. Subtype as parameter not accepted for implementing the interface

Tags: typescript, abstraction

I have a class which extends another class as shown below

```js
abstract class FooAbstract{
    constructor(someProp:any){
        this.someProp = someProp;
    }
    someProp:any;
}

class Foo extends FooAbstract{
    constructor(prop:any){
        super(prop);
    }
    someRandomFunction(){
        console.log("Something")
    }
}
```

I have an interface which has a function as shown below

```js
interface ExampleInterface{
    someFunction: (foo:FooAbstract)=>any;
}
```

Now I want to implement the interface but want to pass subtype as parameter of the function **someFunction** in the interface implementation as shown below

```js
class Example implements ExampleInterface{
    someFunction = (foo:Foo)=>{
        console.log("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Typescript is warning that the implementation of **someFunction** is incorrect and the type Foo and FooAbstract are incompatible. I want to understand why can't I implement the function **someFunction** by requiring as a parameter a subtype of **FooAbstract**

Comment: Because not all `FooAbstract`s are `Foo`s - if `someFunction` relied on `someRandomFunction` then it couldn't accept some implementers of `FooAbstract`. You can't narrow parameter types (similarly you can't broaden return types).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this makes sense because it is not safe to do this. Consider the following scenario:

```
class Example implements ExampleInterface{
    someFunction = (foo:Foo)=>{
        console.log("Hello World");
        foo.someRandomFunction() // we can call this since foo is of type Foo
    }
}
class Boo extends FooAbstract{
    constructor(prop:any){
        super(prop);
    }
    // no someRandomFunction method
}
var ex: ExampleInterface = new Example();
ex.someFunction(new Boo({})) // ok, Boo is derived from FooAbstract
```

If the compiler would allow the scenario in your question, the above code would compile but fail at runtime because `someRandomFunction` does not exist on `Boo`.

You can make the interface generic so you can specify what type of derived `FooAbsrtact` you will use:

```
interface ExampleInterface< T extends FooAbstract >{
    someFunction: (foo:T)=>any;
}
// now ok
class Example implements ExampleInterface<Foo>{
    someFunction = (foo:Foo)=>{
        console.log("Hello World");
        foo.someRandomFunction() 
    }
}
class Boo extends FooAbstract{
    constructor(prop:any){
        super(prop);
    }
    // no someRandomFunction method
}
var ex: ExampleInterface<Foo> = new Example();
ex.someFunction(new Boo({})) // compile error as it should be
```

Comment: Yeah it makes sense. Only the class is abstracted while the function implementation remains. Thanks for the response