# Typescript generics: T extends X all of a sudden wants X to extend T

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am getting an error that my interface `Event` should implement all properties of `MyEvent`, while actualy I want TS to check that `MyEvent` implements `Event`.

My understanding of generics was that I can define a function that accepts type `T extends X` as an argument, but now it's saying that `X doesn't extend T`.

### Background

I'm creating a simple event manager:

```
// imports..

export interface Event {
  getName: () => string;
}

export class EventManager {
  private callbacks; // Typing is unimportant for this example.

  on(eventName: string, cb: <T extends Event>(event: T) => void) {
    // some code..

    this.callbacks[eventName].push(cb);
  }

  // more code..
}
```

Then I try to listen to an event (which triggers an error that confuses me):

```
class MyEvent implements Event {
  // Implement Event interface method.
  getName(): string {
    return 'a';
  }

  // Add other random method.
  getFooBar(): string {
    return 'b';
  }
}

const eventManager = new EventManager();
eventManager.on('test', (e: MyEvent) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Error:

```
TS2345: Argument of type '(e: MyEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '<T extends Event>(event: T) => void'.   
  Types of parameters 'e' and 'event' are incompatible.     
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'MyEvent'.       
      Property 'getFooBar' is missing in type 'Event' but required in type 'MyEvent'.
```

What is going on here? I want the event manager to accept any type of event, hence the `<T extends Event>`, but now it is saying that `Event` should have all properties of `MyEvent` instead that `MyEvent` should have all of the `Event` interface?

(PS: The same happens if instead of accepting type `T` I accept the `Event` interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on` needs to be defined as generic. Something like this:

```
interface Event {
  getName: () => string;
}

class EventManager {
  private callbacks; // Typing is unimportant for this example.

  on<T extends Event>(eventName: string, cb: (event: T) => void) {
    // some code..
  }
  // more code..
}

class MyEvent implements Event {
  // Implement Event interface method.
  getName(): string {
    return 'a';
  }

  // Add other random method.
  getFooBar(): string {
    return 'b';
  }
}

class YourEvent implements Event {
  // Implement Event interface method.
  getName(): string {
    return 'a';
  }

  // Add other random method.
  getBarFoo(): string {
    return 'b';
  }
}

const eventManager = new EventManager();
eventManager.on<MyEvent>('test', (e: MyEvent) => {
  console.log(e);
});

eventManager.on<YourEvent>('test', (e: YourEvent) => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

I think it's just a syntax misunderstanding on your part.

Comment: Beautiful. Two and a half hours spent on this, and all I had to do is move the declaration 20-somewhat characters to the left haha. Indeed, it works. And indeed, I find it weird that the type has to be declared on `on` and not on the callback function, but I guess that's my not-so-proficiency in generics, then.

Comment: Can you maybe answer a last question about this for imaginary bonus points? If I declare the `on` method as follows: `on(eventName: string, cb: (event: Event) => void) {`, I still cannot pass the event to the callback. It says "Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'MyEvent': getFooBar". Again I was expecting that this would work, because `MyEvent` extends `Event`.

Comment: For me, using: `on(eventName: string, cb: (event: Event) => void) {}`, `eventManager.on('test', (e: MyEvent) => {});` does not give errors. It would be nice if you could prepare some code in typescript playground or stackblitz.

Comment: Hey, sorry for that one. I have an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/2t78m

Comment: I see what you mean now. I'm not sure how to answer this, you might want to post another question. Nobody besides me will see this as a comment here

Comment: Will do, thanks for the answer to my original question, anyway!

Comment: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535848/typescript-interface-with-function-subtype-as-parameter-not-accepted-for-implem